# PostgreSQL can't UPSERT with a "WITH"

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I want to upsert a value with a WITH, like this:

```
WITH counted as (
   SELECT votant, count(*) as nbvotes
    FROM votes
    WHERE votant = '123456'
    GROUP BY votant
)

INSERT INTO badges(id, badge, conditions, niveau, date_obtention)
VALUES('123456', 'category', c.nbvotes, 1, current_timestamp)
ON CONFLICT (id, badge)
DO UPDATE badges b
SET b.conditions = c.nbvotes
FROM counted c
WHERE b.id = c.votant AND b.badge = 'category'
```

The console tells me I have an error on "`badges`" just after "`DO UPDATE`"
I really don't understand what goes wrong here, if anybpdy could give me a hand, it would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) the `badges b` after the `do update` part is wrong - and unnecessary if you think of it. The target table is already defined by the `INSERT` part.

But you also don't need a FROM or join to the original value.

So just use:

```
...
ON CONFLICT (id, badge)
DO UPDATE 
  SET conditions = '{"a":"loooool"}';
```

If you need to access the original values, you can use the `excluded` record to refer to it, e.g.

```
  SET conditions = EXCLUDED.conditions
```

which in your case would refer to the rows provided in the `values` clause (`{"a":"lol"}'` in your example)

And target columns of an `UPDATE` cannot be table-qualified. So just `SET conditions = ...`

---

If you want to use the result of the CTE as the source of the INSERT, you need to use an `INSERT ... SELECT`. You can't use a FROM clause in the DO UPDATE part of an INSERT.

```
WITH counted as (
  SELECT votant, count(*) as nbvotes
  FROM votes
  WHERE votant = '123456'
  GROUP BY votant
)
INSERT INTO badges(id, badge, conditions, niveau, date_obtention)
SELECT '123456', 'category', c.nbvotes, 1, current_timestamp
FROM counted c
ON CONFLICT (id, badge)
DO UPDATE 
   SET conditions = excluded.conditions
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed I changed my example to show how I'd like to use the "counted" table. With your explanations I managed to solve the "badge" problem,

Comment: @djcaesar9114: see my edit. Btw: why are you storing numbers as strings? That is a really bad idea.

Comment: Actually although I put '123456', the value can be 'TESTLOL48694', but thanks for your remark, I should have put another value to prevent misleading information in my example.